# Is there anyway to cache the loaded file data

Tags: java, php, performance, caching

There is my issue:

I already have a java script that needs to be executed (with a php script) when user input something, and it's working fine.

```
exec("java <script_name> $inputContent", $output);
```

But it takes time to load script data first.

For example, in case I want to search a string from a large array (array is dynamic loaded from a large file), its take about 10s (to load the array) for each execution.

If I run it directly on the terminal, it only takes 10s for the first time,  I can use the loop to do a lot of searches, that's good.

Is there any way to make the same way for php scripts, or cache array data somewhere?

Thank you all!

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Java dude, Java script mean a script of Java, it's about server issue

Comment: Maybe change the Java program so it can take multiple `$inputContent` arguments, and it loops over them without having to reload the data.

Comment: But you tagged it `javascript`, which means the JavaScript language, not a script written in Java.

Comment: @Barmar re But you tagged it javascript, it's java tag

Comment: @Barmar re it can take multiple $inputContent arguments, I can not do this because user need to run multiple times whenever they want :(

Comment: I fixed the tag for you, it was originally `javascript`. Anyway, this isn't really a PHP or shell issue, they have nothing to do with the way the Java program works. You need to design it so it can save the data in a more easily loaded form. If you want help with that, you need to post the program.

Comment: @Barmar ah, sorry, it's my mistake, thank you